# Query the entire Active Directory and its GC Servers for a list of AD users

Tags: powershell, foreach

My intention is to query the entire Active Directory Domain, which incorporates a total of 5 Global Catalogue Servers ($ServerList), for a list of AD users in a text file ($UserList) in order to check if the users are still enabled and what server their accounts are located in. The catch in here is that to find a user account listed in the text file, I need to query all 5 GC servers.

As a One-liner, I've tried the following statements to do this:

```
$UserList | %{get-aduser -Server $ServerList -f "userprincipalname -like '*$_*'" -Properties UserPrincipalName, Enabled}| Export-Csv .\output.txt
```

My attempt returns the following error:
Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Server'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:29

```
The content of the Server List is in this format:
server1.xxx.com
server2.xxx.com
server3.xxx.com
server4.xxx.com
server5.xxx.com
```

I think somewhere in the line, the foreach iteration has to be placed, but my attempts didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-Server` expects a single string whereas you're passing it an array of strings:

```
foreach ($server in $serverList)
{
    foreach ($user in $userList) 
    {
        try {
            Get-ADUser -Filter "userprincipalname -like '*$user*'" -Properties "UserPrincipalName", "Enabled" -Server $server | Export-Csv -Path ".\output.txt" -Append -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation 
        } 
        catch { }
    }
}
```

So two loops are needed.

1. First one to iterate through your server list.

   - `$serverList`
2. Second one to iterate though your user list

   - `$userList`

---

*Hopefully I understood you correctly and this was what you were looking for. :)*

Comment: Hi Abraham, thanks for your quick response and resolution.

Comment: When I run your script, it actually took many hours for it to complete. Moreover, it didn't appear to have processed all accounts or maybe didn't run through all the servers. 
Would there be a way to speed up the script and process all users in the list (~650 users)?

Comment: Here's the code I've been running manually one by one after another for each 5 servers and which took only ~30 minutes to complete, providing a complete result:

gc .\userlist.txt | %{get-aduser -server "Server1.com" -f "userprincipalname -like '$_*'" -properties userprincipalname, enabled} | Select-Object userprincipalname, enabled | Export-Csv .\output.txt